# Encoding of non-ASCII characters (Umlauts) in \jobname

Tags: pdftex, unicode, input-encodings, jobname

I need to parse `\jobname` to extract some metadata (such as the subject of a letter) that is encoded in the filename of the `.tex` file. The filenames are not restricted to ASCII, but maybe any UTF8 charcater. In particular, I have lots of files with German Umlauts in their name. However, compiling:

```
% Änderungen.tex
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
  \jobname
\end{document}
```

with `pdflatex` yields:

[image]

With `lualatex` or `xelatex` the output is fine; however, I would prefer to stay with `pdflatex`. So how is `\jobname` actually encoded and how can I transform it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you only need to print the jobname, then

```
\scantokens\expandafter{\jobname\noexpand}
```

is sufficient. The problem is that all characters in the expansion of `\jobname` have category code 12, so they aren't interpreted in the correct way for printing. With `\scantokens` we make TeX reread them, but first we need to expand `\jobname`. The final `\noexpand` is for avoiding a spurious space at the end.

If instead you want to store the "retokenized" name in a control sequence, then using LaTeX3 is easier:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\UTFjobname}{o}
 {
  \tl_set_rescan:NnV \l_tmpa_tl { } \c_sys_jobname_str
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
   { \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl }
   { \tl_set_eq:NN #1 \l_tmpa_tl }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_set_rescan:Nnn {NnV}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\scantokens\expandafter{\jobname\noexpand}X

\UTFjobname X

\UTFjobname[\foo]\show\foo

\end{document}
```

With only `\UTFjobname` you print the jobname, with `\UTFjobname[\foo]` you store the jobname (with the correct category codes) in `\foo`. The `X` are there just to show that no space is added when printing.

[image]

The terminal will stop at `\show\foo` with

```
> \foo=macro:
->Änderungen.
l.20 \UTFjobname[\foo]\show\foo
```

### Note

As of September 2015, the constant `\c_job_name_tl` has been removed and changed into `\c_sys_jobname_str`. The code has been updated accordingly.